# debug PostgreSQL function in pgAdmin: installation script fails

Tags: debugging, pgadmin

I have 9.2 installed and wanted to try the debugger.  Followed the instructions for enabling it, including making sure user was superuser, but Debug option remains grayed out on the Tools menu and does not appear in the treeview's context-menu when a function is right-clicked.

I note that `pldbgapi.sql` does not exist but there is a file called `pldbgapi--1.0.sql`.

When `pldbgapi--1.0.sql` is opened in the Query window and Execute Script is invoked, it fails on the line:

```
  DO $do$
```

with an invalid character error. It does not like "DO".  I also had to wrap comment lines beginning with `--` in `/* */`.

Why is execute script crashing at `DO`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One must go to the Tools menu, Server Configuration, postgresql.conf, and when the configuration file is opened, there will be a checkbox next to each configuration item. Scroll down to *shared_preload_libraries*, and click on the checkbox to enable it. Save the configuration. Stop and restart the database.

Comment: Not sure about the crash at `DO`